# Verwendung von »dieser« und »jener«

Tags: word-usage, difference, pronoun

Ich habe bisher nicht oft *dieser* und *jener* sinnvoll verwendet, aber oft gelesen, dass *dieser* auf zeitlich und räumlich Näheres verweist als *jener.* Dies gilt auch für zeitlich näher Erwähntes in einem Text. Klar, genau wie bei *hic* und *ille.* Nur aber bin ich mit denen auch nicht so vertraut.

Da nämlich komme ich hier ins stolpern:

> Metaller mögen Hip-Hopper nicht, denn diese hören Musik, jene nur Krach.
>   Metaller und Hip-Hopper mögen einander nicht; diese hören Krach, jene Musik.

Natürlich liest man sofort aus dem Kontext, dass mit *diese* im ersten Satz die Hip-Hopper, im zweiten die Metaller gemeint sind und andersrum. Aber wie erkennt man das, wenn man nicht weiß, dass Hip-Hop die weit höherwertige Musik ist als Metal?

Wie verwendet man nun die beiden Begriffe? In welcher Grammatik kann ich das nachschlagen? Oder war die Verwendung in dem Beispiel, etwa im zweiten Satz nicht korrekt?

Comment: Das ist übrigens keine schlecht gestellte, unsinnige und vollkommen uninteressante Frage. Ich fordere Downvoter auf, sich zu erklären!

Comment: Bei der Art, wie hier Sprechgelabere mit Musik verwechselt wird, stellen sich mir meine Metallerhaare zu Berge …

Comment: @Jan : ⟩ Wenn’s dich beruhigt: Ich halte Metal für die anspruchsvollere Musik.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Über den Inhalt deiner Beispiele kann man streiten, aber grammatikalisch hast du dir ein Eigentor geschossen. Beide Sätze sagen etwas unterschiedliches aus.

*Dies* verwendet man für alles, was einem räumlich oder zeitlich näher steht.

> Dies ist meine Freundin und jene ist seine Freundin.
>
> Du musst das an diesem Tag noch erledigen, was du an jenem Tag nicht geschafft hast.

Ist eine räumliche bzw. zeitliche Einordnung schwer möglich, bezieht sich *dies* auf das **zuletzgenannte**.

> Auf dem Foto siehst du mein Auto und meine Yacht, diese steht an der Cote d'Azur und jenes in meiner Garage.

Üblicherweise verwendet man aber wohl eher *ersteres* und *letzteres*. Dann hat man das Problem auch gar nicht.

[Dies](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-dieser-jener3.html?lang=de) ist meine Quelle.

Comment: Laut der Quelle, in welcher ein ganz analoges Beispiel (das mit dem Herzog und der Herzögin) angeführt wird, wäre die Verwendung der Wörter im zweiten Beispielsatz also falsch! +1 für Zusammenfassen und Angeben der Quelle, die [erklärt](http://www.canoo.net/services/ueberblick/verantwortung.html), dass die bereitgestellte „Grammatik […] von Stephan Bopp, einem an der Universität Zürich promovierten Linguisten zusammengestellt [wurde].“ (Accept folgt, nachdem ich mir eventuell in nächster Zeit kommende, konkurriende Antworten angeschaut habe.)

Comment: Kleine Anmerkung: Zuvor ging ich davon aus, dass der Parallelismus, der diesen Beispielsätzen innewohnt, gerade die gegenteilige Verwendung von „dies” und „jenes” bewirkt, als ob man die logischen (Sub-/)Objekte links und rechts anordnet und in der Wahl des näher- und fernerstehend Bezeichnenden in derselben Reihenfolge vorgeht, „dies“ also auf links verweist, „jenes“ auf das Rechte.

Comment: @K.Stm. Die Idee dahinter versteh ich, aber es ist eben halt eine logische Konsequenz, dass *dies* das näher stehende und folglich das letztere Objekt referenziert.

Comment: +1 weil es zeigt, welch kranke (?) Zusammenhänge man intuitiv richtig berücksichtigt beim alltäglichen Formulieren, ohne sich dieser (jener?) Zusammenhänge bewusst zu sein.

Comment: Das Beispiel mit die Auto und die Yacht ist schlecht gewählt, weil ...

Comment: @k.stm Nein, Nein, offensichtlich ist nur der zweite Beispielsatz richtig, denn wer will ernsthaft behaupten, Hip-Hop habe etwas mit Musik zu tun? \m/

Comment: @Jan Hip-Hop *ist* Musik, wenn man Musik nicht gerade sehr eng fasst. (Und selbst dann ist zumindest einiger Hip-Hop noch Musik.) Das’ ziemlich off-topic, aber wenn du möchtest, können wir uns jetzt eben im Chat dazu battlen.

Comment: Ich wollte das ja irgendwann mal accepten. Ist jetzt nachgeholt.

Answer (score 2):

In den genannten Beispielen schlüpfen "dieser" und "jener" in die Rollen von "der eine" und "der andere".

> Raben mögen Möwen nicht. Diese sind schwarz, jene sind weiß.
>   Raben mögen Möwen nicht. Die einen sind schwarz, die anderen sind weiß.

Diese Konstruktion setzt aber voraus, dass "diese" und "jene" im selben (Teil-)Satz stehen und dass sie Gegensätze ausdrücken. Auch zwingend notwendig: Es werden genau zwei (also nicht drei oder mehr) Objekte verglichen.

Deine Beobachtung, dass das Wort "diese" auf nahe Objekte angewandt wird, während "jene" für ferne Objekte verwendet wird, hat mit deinem Beispiel nichts zu tun, weil "diese" und "jene" hier in einem ganz anderen Kontext Verwendung finden.

Comment: +1 für die Beobachtung mit „der eine“ und „der andere“! Kannst du das ein bisschen näher erläutern? Darf ich da außerdem wieder nach einer Quelle fragen?

Comment: Was willst du da noch näher erläutert haben? Und was für eine Quelle brauchst du da noch? Wenn ich dir sage, dass ein Streichholz und ein Zündholz dasselbe sind, kann ich das auch nicht mit irgendwelchen Quellen belegen oder es näher erläutern.

Comment: Man hätte, wäre es beispielsweise um ein Verb gegangen, auf das schöne Wörterbuch zur Valenz und Distribution Deutscher Verben von Helbig und Schenkel verweisen können, und noch mal genauer zu anderen Verwendungsmöglichkeiten der Wörter abgrenzen können. Ich finde es gewissermaßen logisch, was du schreibst, aber es reicht mir nicht ganz zu einem Gesamtbild; die Möglichkeit, mir dazu Weiteres anzuschauen, fehlt mir.

Comment: @K.Stm.: Ich habe Chemie, Physik und Wirtschafts-Informatik studiert, habe zwei Jahrzehnte als Datenmanager im Finanz-Bereich hinter mir und arbeite jetzt als selbstständiger Softwareentwickler und -designer. Deutsch ist meine Muttersprache, und bei mir daheim stehen knapp 3000 Bücher herum (vor allem technische Fachbücher und Belletristik). Daher kenne ich den praktischen Gebrauch dieser Sprache sehr gut. Aber bei der Theorie musst du leider auf Antworten von anderen Usern hoffen.

Comment: Ja ja, praktisch setze ich auch die meisten Kommata richtig, aber theoretisch.... :O

Comment: Zu dieser Antwort wurde eine Änderung vorgeschlagen: http://german.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13308 Die ist inhaltlich auf jeden Fall richtig („Diese sind schwarz, jene sind weiß“ oben besagt, daß Raben weiß und Möwen schwarz sind), ich glaube aber, daß du hier bewußt das Gegenteil behauptest und habe die Änderung daher abgelehnt (Begründung: verändert die beabsichtigte Aussage). Vielleicht kannst du noch einmal klarstellen, ob „Diese sind schwarz …“ deiner Meinung nach dasselbe wie „Die einen sind schwarz …“ bedeutet oder das Gegenteil..

Comment: @chirlu: Die Änderung hat ein anonymer User vorgeschlagen, sie war nicht in meinem Sinn. Ich danke dir, dass du sie abgelehnt hast.

Answer (score -3):

Oft wird vereinfacht dargestellt (wie im grammatikalisch korrekten Hiphop-Metal-Vergleich), dass es bei *dieses* und *jenes* darum geht, was im Satz näher steht (für das weiter entfernte verwendet man *jener/jenes*). Meist liegt man damit richtig. Das Sprachgefühl sagt hier aber ganz eindeutig, dass es eigentlich nicht um den Satzbau geht, sondern um das konkret räumlich oder zeitlich Näherstehende. Ein Beispiel:

> [...] Das Gelbe ist der Gartenschlauch!
>   Den braucht sie zum Autowaschen
>   Jenes zum Nach-Gehrden-Fahr’n [...]

Das Auto steht im Satz näher, ist aber beim Autowaschen räumlich weiter entfernt als der Schlauch, den man dabei ja in der Hand hält. Ich hoffe, mein Sprachgefühl trifft hier auf Zustimmung, sonst muss ich ein Gedicht umschreiben.

Comment: Ich verstehe das "Gedicht" nicht. Deswegen verstehe ich auch deine Erklärung nicht und habe die Frage abgewertet.

Answer (score -5):

"Dieses" und "jenes" sind Synonyme und somit absolut gleichwertig.

Man benutzt Beide, um auf zwei Dinge zu verweisen, ohne zwei mal "dieses" zu sagen.

EDIT:

Antwort auf deine erste Frage: Generell entscheidet die Reihenfolge wofür dieses/jenes stehen, wie in deinem zweiten Beispiel. Wenn du aber "denn" benutzt, "ziehst" du die Hip-Hopper sozusagen "vor".

Allerdings gibt es keine fixe Regel, man muss aus dem Kontext lesen welche Wörter von dieses/jenes ersetzt werden.

Comment: Das ist eine durch und durch unbefriedigende Antwort, viel weniger, als was ich bereits festgehalten habe, und ich zweifle absolut an, dass man die Wörter synonym verwenden kann. Die Erklärung mit der Reihenfolge ist auch sehr dürftig. Es ist nirgendworauf verwiesen worden. Daher ein Downvote.

Comment: Deutsch ist meine Muttersprache, auf mehr kann ich leider nicht verweisen. Es sind Synonyme. Auf was sich die beiden Wörter beziehen ist nicht klar geregelt, es gibt immer wieder Missverständnisse, meistens stimmt die bereits oben genannte Regel (Reihenfolge), aber nicht immer, wie in deinem ersten Beispiel zu sehen ist. Generell kann man aus dem Kontext erkennen was gemeint ist, Sätze mit einer dieses/jenes-Konstruktion sollten entsprechend klar formuliert werden.

Comment: Ok, aber ich bin auch Muttersprachler. Der Witz ist ja, dass ich ja gerade nach einer grammatikalischen Regel frage. Ich habe ja ohnehin schon festgehalten, dass es eine Regel zu geben scheint, nach der die Reihenfolge entscheindend ist, und dass man es oft aus dem Kontext erschließen hat. Bei dem Beispiel, weswegen ich es gewählt habe, ist es jedoch, wenn man die Meinung des Autors nicht kennt, nicht ersichtlich, was gemeint ist, denn die beiden Parteien werfen ja einander dieselben Argumente vor. Und die These, dass beide Wörter synonym sind, ist unbegründet und ich halte sie für falsch.

Comment: Das ist also, kurz gesprochen, keine Antwort auf die Frage, die ja, vielleicht nicht explizit, um eine gewisse (grammatikalische) Auseinandersetzung mit diesen Wörtern bittet. (Übrigens, wäre es falsch, hier "jenen" zu verwenden?, würde das eventuell einen Bedeutungsunterschied ausmachen?) Ich sehe auch jetzt gerade, dass das dein erster Post ist. Sorry, ich will dich auf keinen Fall verscheuchen, aber nach Prinzip muss ich auch downvoten. Herzlich willkommen aber!

Comment: zu herzlich -.- ich denke dass es auf diese Frage keine Antwort gibt, da, meines Wissens nach, keine eindeutige Regel existiert. Aber wenn dir das nicht reicht, bzw du sicher bist dass es jene gibt kann ich dir leider nicht weiterhelfen.

Comment: Sorry, diese Antwort ist schlichtweg falsch. Es gibt einen Unterschied, genauso, wie's im Englischen ein Unterschied zw. "this/these" und "that/those" gibt (oder sogar yonder). --- Es gibt schon seinen Grund, warum man öfters *dies* verwendet.

Comment: @le_me Es kann schon sein, dass sich keine Struktur in der Verwendung erkennen lässt, aber ein solches Urteil ist unaussagekräftig, wenn es nicht gerade von jemandem stammt, der sich intensiv mit Sprache, Deutsch und speziell dem Problem befasst hat. Einen solchen Aufwand sieht man deiner Antwort bloß nicht an. Daher reicht mir das tatsächlich nicht. (Trotzdem danke, aber.)

Comment: gerne, ich habe das mir Mögliche getan, ich wusste nicht wie genau du deine Antwort brauchst ;)

Comment: Das ist weder richtig noch eine Antwort auf die Frage.

Comment: der erste Satz erregt Anstoß... zu recht. Den zweiten finde ich nicht so schlecht. Er erklärt auf jeden Fall einen Teil der Fälle

Comment: Ich habe "dieses, jenes, welches" auch als Synonyme kennengelernt und muss die Antwort aufwerten.